# C# List with changing variable

Tags: c#, list, overriding, var

I have a List containing an object like this:

```
List<unit> unitlist = new List<unit>();
```

With unit beeing initialized like this:

```
 public class unit
    {
        public string[] records;
    }
```

I then use a variable to add into the list:

```
var temp = new unit();
temp.records = csv.GetFieldHeaders; // using lumenworks framework to read a csv
unitlist.Add(temp);
```

When I now override temp with a new item line from the csv, the entry in the list unitlist is also changed:

```
while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < csv.Fieldcount; i++) 
    {
        // Read the csv entry in the temp variable
        temp.records[i] = csv[i];
    }
    // check for specific field, and write to list
    if (temp.records[8] == "Ja")
        unitlist.Add(temp);
}
```

When I now check unitlist, all the entries are the last read line from the csv, because they all are changed when the temp-variable changes. Why is that the case? How can I separate the List unitlist from the variable temp?

Comment: You need to create new object var temp = new unit(); every time in the loop then add it into the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using the same bucket to store things in.

If you create `temp` every time, this should fix your problem

```
var header = new unit();
header.records = csv.GetFieldHeaders; 
unitlist.Add(header);

...

while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
{
    var temp = new unit();
    temp.records = new string[header.records.Length]

    for (int i = 0; i < csv.Fieldcount; i++) 
    {
        // Read the csv entry in the temp variable
        temp.records[i] = csv[i];
    }
    // check for specific field, and write to list
    if (temp.records[8] == "Ja")
        unitlist.Add(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved it.  
Why is the  
    temp.records = new string[header.records.Length];  
necessary?  
I thought I have the string-array initialized with the initialization of the unit-class.

Comment: @LucasEhrler because when you create temp, it has an empty array

Answer (score 0):

You need to create temp object in each iteration like below. Please try this and check.

```
while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
{
    var temp = new unit();
    temp.records = csv.GetFieldHeaders;

    for (int i = 0; i < csv.Fieldcount; i++) 
    {
        // Read the csv entry in the temp variable
        temp.records[i] = csv[i];
    }
    // check for specific field, and write to list
    if (temp.records[8] == "Ja")
        unitlist.Add(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the `temp` variable, it is referencing a location in memory where your object data is allocated. When you add it to `unitlist`, a reference is added to the list that points to the same location in memory.

Now, when you change `temp.records[i]`, it is *updated* in that same memory location. So, you end up with a list of items, all pointing to the same object in memory, containing the last `records` in the CSV file.

Simply adding a `temp = new unit();` at the beginning of your `while` loop will cause each iteration to allocation a new object, with a new memory location, and have `temp` reference it.